# How can I have some of the functions in separate file?

Tags: rust, substrate-node-template

I want to keep some helper functions in a separate file. How can I do that?

```
impl<T: Config> Pallet<T> {
        fn get_citizen_accountid(citizenid: u128) ->
        fn get_citizen_id(accountid: T::AccountId) -> 
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `#[pallet]` macro parts of your pallet code cannot be refactored into a separate file.

So things like:

- `#[pallet::storage]`
- `#[pallet::config]`
- `#[pallet::call]`
- etc...

Must all be within the:

```rust
#[frame_support::pallet]
pub mod pallet { ... }
```

And unfortunately, due to Rust not handling cross file macros, these must all be together.

However, pretty much everything else can be refactored into separate files using [Rust's module system](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/mod.html).

So just put your type definitions or additional function helpers into a separate file, and import it like so:

**lib.rs**

```rust
mod extra;
mod types;

#[frame_support::pallet]
pub mod pallet { ... }
```

**extra.rs**

```rust
use crate::*;

impl<T: Config> Pallet<T> {
    pub fn do_stuff() -> DispatchResult {
        // ...
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

**types.rs**

```rust
use codec::{Decode, Encode, MaxEncodedLen};
use scale_info::TypeInfo;

#[derive(Encode, Decode, PartialEq, Debug, Clone, Copy, MaxEncodedLen, TypeInfo)]
pub struct MyStruct {
    pub item1: u64,
    pub item2: u64,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Decided to use include! micro

```
include!("helperfunctions.rs");
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35158265/1566713